# need Asp.net 2.0 chart control

Tags: asp.net

I want to know which chart is compatible  with asp.net 2.0.

I need some sample code on how to implement those chart controls ?

Comment: why not you are trying JS/Jquery charts? I think highslide available in .net version also http://highcharts.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before switching to Microsofts Charting ( and . NET 3.5 ) we used http://www.dotnetcharting.com/

I have Not implemented it by myself, but there are many samples on their site. They are kompatible with .NET 2 still as I have read briefly their feature page.

Comment: is it free ??. can u send some example

Comment: It has some license costs. Look at their page - they have tons of examples.

Answer (score 0):

Use
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/24/new-asp-net-charting-control-lt-asp-chart-runat-quot-server-quot-gt.aspx
Thanks

Comment: "that can be used for free with ASP.NET 3.5" - he asked for a .NET 2 control. Sure this is the one? It's the same CLR, but it probably references 3.5 assemblies

Comment: @rakesh : These charts are also paid

Comment: @rakesh : if u use this commercially, then u have to purchase license.